# Redis: count specific class of keys on a Redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Is there an efficient method to count specific class of keys on a Redis cluster?

Here, 'specific class of keys' means the keys that are used for a common purpose; for example, session keys. They can have a common key name prefix. There can be multiple classes. From now, I will refer the class of keys as simply the keys.

What I want to do is as follows:

- Redis cluster must be used.
- The keys must be distributed to the nodes of the Redis cluster.
- There must be an efficient way to count the number of the keys on all of the nodes of the Redis cluster.
- The keys can have TTL - that is, can expire.
- The number of the nodes of the Redis cluster can be changed on runtime, and hash slots can be redistributed.
- Clients are implemented using Node.js.

I've read the documentation, but could not find a proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically. That doesn't exist for "classic" (non-cluster), either. To do that without an additional storage mechanism, you would need to use `SCAN` repeatedly to iterate over the entire keyspace. Fortunately it does at least accept a filter (so you don't need to fetch every key), but is far from efficient - you'd typically only do this periodically as a review feature, not an operational feature. We actually include such a feature in "opserver"'s redis plugin.

When you switch to cluster, you'd need to repeat this but on one of each set of replication verticals. You would typically get that list via the `CLUSTER` commands, so the dynamic nature of the nodes is moot.

In both classic and cluster, it would be recommended to only do this on a replica - not the master. And again: only as an admin tool, not as a routine part of your system.

Do not use `KEYS` to do this. Prefer `SCAN`.